# どうぞよろしくお願いします meaning

Tags: words

> メインビジュアルを公開！パッケージにも使用予定のイラストです！発売まであと3カ月を切った本作をどうぞよろしくお願いします！

Discolsure of the main visual!
The illustration that is planned to be used on the package!
Thank you in advance for this work which will release in less than 3 months.

What does

> をどうぞよろしくお願いします

Mean here?

That was my translation.

2 other questions.

is

> 発売まであと3カ月を切った本作

The work that in less than 3 months will be released?

I think that timeを切る means something like: In less than 
本作=It can be used for games too I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> をどうぞよろしくお願いします

Well, firstly phrases like よろしくお願いします and お疲れ様 don't have a definite English translation. どうぞよろしくお願いします is just a more polite way to say よろしくお願いします, which in this case means either 'thank you for your support' or 'thank you for considering this work', as artists / writers are known to say some forms of this phrase.

By the way, 'in advance' is not expressed at all, and if you want to express that or 'ongoing support', you can append '今後も～'

> あと３ヶ月を切った

You're right, this means under 3 months. The full translation would be "It'll go on sale in less than 3 months from now!"

> 本作

is basically 'this piece of work', so it can be practically anything from films to books to games.